# i have set path of ndk-build in windows 8 but still getting error in path?

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-ndk

14:33:33 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing ****
"

```
E:\\java & tc\\android\\NVPACK\\android-ndk-r8-crystax-1\\ndk-build\\ndk-build.cmd" 
Cannot run program "E:\java & tc\android\NVPACK\android-ndk-r8-crystax-1\ndk-build\ndk-build.cmd": Launching failed

Error: Program "E:\java & tc\android\NVPACK\android-ndk-r8-crystax-1\ndk-build\ndk-build.cmd" not found in PATH

PATH=[C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;E:\java & tc\android\NVPACK\android-ndk-r8-crystax-1\ndk-build]

14:33:33 Build Finished (took 138ms)
```

this is the error i am getting...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Cygwin` directory into your `PATH` too. To add to path right click `Computer->Properties->Advanced System Settings-> "Advanced" tab -> Environment Variables`